# matrix optimization in diagonal and orthonormality constraint

Tags: convex-optimization, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition, orthonormal

I'd like to solve the following optimization problem.

Y is a CxN matrix A is a CxC and diagonal matrix Q is a CxC and orthonormal matrix X is a CxN matrix

$$
min_{A,Q} {|| Y − AQX ||}^2_F
$$

The question is how to optimize over A and Q.

Does anyone know how to take derivative wrt. diagonal and orthonormal matrix?

Comment: do you know how to solve for $Q$ if $A$ is known ?

Comment: This looks as one of the "generalized Procustes optimization problems". These kind of problems more or less all deal with Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) (derivation is not the mean tool). Have a look at www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/talks/procrust94.ps.gz

Comment: Thanks a lot for replying. If there were no A or no Q matrix in the formula, it can be solved. but the problem arise when we want to optimize with constraint on two matrices.

Comment: This is not a convex optimization problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: @user1952009 does it make it much simpler if we know A to be X^T?